# PHPWord - Add links inside HTML paragraphs

Tags: phpword

I am trying to convert HTML into DOCX using [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord).

`addHtml` function converts my HTML, but strips any `a href` links.

How can I convert the HTML while keeping the links inside paragraphs and other HTML elements?

---

Example:

`<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla faucibus nisl neque, sit <a href="http://www.test.com">amet mollis ante</a> accumsan et. Phasellus tincidunt nisi a dui gravida, pulvinar auctor arcu egestas. Etiam non ultrices risus. Ut mattis tempus velit a sodales. Proin id sodales sem.</p>`

After conversion to DOCX, should be:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla
>   faucibus nisl neque, sit [amet mollis
>   ante](http://www.test.com) accumsan et. Phasellus tincidunt nisi a dui gravida, pulvinar
>   auctor arcu egestas. Etiam non ultrices risus. Ut mattis tempus velit
>   a sodales. Proin id sodales sem.

Comment: Indeed, PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html is currently not parsing the <a> tag, I'll try to come up with something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functionality was added:

```
Add parsing of <a href="">
```

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/pull/1258